# Validating against XSD file and ignoring schemaLocation in XML in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, xsd-validation

I made simple Validating of an XML file. It works fine until the file have no schemaLocation attribute. If the attribute is defined, then the logic ignores my specified XSD file. Do you have some idea, how can I always validate against the XSD from SchemaSet?

Here is my code:

```cs
public static bool Validate (string xmlFile, string xsdFile)
{
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.Schemas.Add("", xsdFile);
    settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;

    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlFile, settings))
    {
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        document.Load(reader);
        System.Console.WriteLine(settings.Schemas.Count);

        ValidationEventHandler eventHandler = new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationEventHandler);

        // the following call to Validate succeeds.
        document.Validate(eventHandler);
    }

    return true;    
}

static void ValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Severity)
    {
        case XmlSeverityType.Error:
            throw new System.Exception(e.Message);                                    
    }
}
```

In my case, I use some XSD to different XML-File. So it should always throw one error that element "Document" is not allowed.

If the XML is without any attributes, the validation works fine:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
  <BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.02">
    <GrpHdr>
      <MsgId>TEST-fbbd57f6285403ad2b146ccbe8ceed</MsgId>
      <CreDtTm>2017-08-18T10:55:35.906+02:00</CreDtTm>
```

If I specify the XML with attributes, I get no validation error (as it validates against referenced schema from attributes):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.02" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.02 camt.054.001.02.xsd">
  <BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.02">
    <GrpHdr>
      <MsgId>TEST-fbbd57f6285403ad2b146ccbe8ceed</MsgId>
      <CreDtTm>2017-08-18T10:55:35.906+02:00</CreDtTm>
```

Comment: The schema add is only needed when writing the xml (serialize) and not when deserialize.  The classes/Properties have a [XmlElement(ElementName = "myclass", Namespace = "URl")]  You need to add the Namespace to the classes.

Comment: Why are schemas only for writing in the XmlReaderSettings?

Comment: That is the Microsoft Design.  The namespaces for reading are determined by the Namespace parameter in the attributes above the classes and properties.

Answer (score 0):

I must define the Namespace. Then it works and it can be made so simple in my case:

```
      public static bool Validate (string xmlFile, string xsdFile)
        {

            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlFile))
            {
                XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
                document.Load(reader);
                document.Schemas.Add(document.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI, xsdFile);

                ValidationEventHandler eventHandler = new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationEventHandler);

                document.Validate(eventHandler);
            }

            return true;
            
        }

        static void ValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.Severity)
            {
                case XmlSeverityType.Error:
                    throw new System.Exception(e.Message);                                    
            }
        }
```